# cant open yourkit profiler on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, yourkit

I am trying to run YourKit a java profiler on ubuntu desktop, the process starts but the UI is not displayed. 
I googled for this problem and found [this](http://forums.yourkit.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6440) article which suggests steps to get around this problem, I tried all the suggestions there but it does not seem to work on my system. If anyone has insight/expertise please share it.

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded to ubuntu-14 and retried running yourkit profiler, and it worked. There is a small caveat though - one might see only a thin vertical window which is 3 or 4 cms in width. This window can be maximized and all the subsequent attempts to open yourkit would NOT require any manual intervention to resize the window.

Answer (score 0):

I enabled the workspaces in 
System Configuration - Appearance - Behaviour - Enable workspaces. And then disabled them again.

This made the window appear in my current screen.

It was just a small bar I could see, but when I maximized it, there it was! The YourKit application.

The place I found this solution that worked for me:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/83176/how-do-i-quickly-switch-between-workspaces-in-unity

I hope this helps.